# My map v3 street view panorama acts in a strange way

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good morning friends, am working on a project, an android project using map v3 on an android webview. I noticed that sometimes my street view doesn't work correctly. It shows blank sometimes. I also noticed that my street view doesn't show panorama pictures for this address "Arsenal,london borough of Islington,United Kingdom", and from there on words, any address typed does not show street view panorama pictures. I also noticed that the same address shows in other application I have tested it in. Finally does JavaScript alert work in android webview, my own is not working. Here is my code below.

```
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573, -71.098326);
  var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    streetViewControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {     
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
    mapTypeIds: [       
      google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,       
      google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
           ]     
       }
   };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 34,
      pitch: 10
    }
  };

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
  map.setStreetView(panorama);


   google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'status_changed', function() {
   document.getElementById("loading1").style.display = "none";
  });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
      });
  document.getElementById( "cancel" ).onclick = function() {
         document.getElementById("autocomplete").value = "";
        };
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
  document.getElementById("loading1").style.display = "none";
      });

}


  function codeAddress() {


   var address = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;

   if(address=='') {
    alert("Type a valid address");
      }
   else {

    document.getElementById("loading1").style.display = "block";

    var address = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status1) {
    if (status1 == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

       streetViewService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
       STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE = 100;

       streetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation(results[0].geometry.location, STREETVIEW_MAX_DISTANCE, function (streetViewPanoramaData, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                   panorama.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                  }
            if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
                   alert("Can not be found");
                  }
              else {
                alert("Street view not available in your location");
                 }

           });

         }

     else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status1);
               }
          });
        }
           }


  <body  bgcolor="#F2F2F2" onload="initialize()">

    <div id="loading1">
      <img id="loading-image1" src="images/loading1.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>


   <div id="adds"></div>

   <div id="loading">
      <img id="loading-image" src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
   </div>
   <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter address,city,country" type="text"></input>
      <img id="cancel" src="images/cancel.png" alt="Loading..."/>
   </div>

    <input id="button" type="button" name="test" value="Search"  style=" font-size:15pt; background-color:#2E2E2E; color:#2EFEF7;" onclick="codeAddress()">

    <div id="pano" style="width: 100%; height: 48%;"></div>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 25%;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is `Arsenal,london borough of Islington,United Kingdom` a valid street address? If not, you might try Google Maps Place API, it [provide text search feature](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search).

Comment: I use google places text search feature for my textfield. The problem is the same address works in other street view application but doesn't work in my own. I don't just know why, please do you have an idea?